# Wierd WiFi Network called ALF

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have lived in three houses in Florida with quite a bit of geography between them. This WiFi network called ALF pops up from time to time. I don't know if it is being generate by a device that I have or if there is something else generating the network. I have four devices running Windows 10, Windows 8, OS X Sierra and my phone. ALF is listed as an SSID on all of the devices when it shows up. It is listed as a secure network. I did not try to access it. It only shows up periodically. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to when I pick it up. The signal strength tends to be 3 bars which is strong. My own Wifi router is 3 to 4 bars. The neighbor's WiFi is 2 bars. How do I 1) rule out my own devices 2) ensure that my network is secure 3) identify the source if it is not one of my devices?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I up dated my question. Hopefully it is more concise. I appreciate the feed back.

Comment: What is the question? Why does this matter? Do you operate in such an isolated environment that you somehow don’t expect to see other WiFi networks? I can easily see dozens of networks each day anywhere I am.

Comment: I also have an xBox One and an Apple TV. Both are hard wired to the router.

Comment: It only matters because I moved across the state and it is still there. If it is one of my devices then I would want to know and secure it. If it isn't then it may pose a security risk.

Comment: Googling "ALF Florida" reveals "Assisted Living Florida". Given Florida's reputation as a retirement state for most of the east coast, maybe you've always lived near some kind of elder-care facility under the auspices of ALF. Also, Wi-Fi networks that come and go are sometimes the onboard Wi-Fi hotspots of shuttle busses. Any chance an elder transport service shuttle was going by your house?

Comment: I lived next to a college at my first house. No assisted living facilities there. That is why I posted here. I was not making any progress on google.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is innocuous. I started doing business out of my house and I am suddenly a little paranoid about security. Interesting about the transports I didn't think about that.

Comment: It seems strong for public transportation also. The buss stop is blocks away. The public transportation system is different than the first house also.

Comment: Is there a way to rule out my own devices other than attempting to access ALF? I would rather not try to access it.

Comment: I am not sure why I am receiving down votes on my question without comments on how to improve it.

Comment: Your question boils down to, *"I don't know if it is being generate by a device that I have or if there is something else generating the network....Has anyone else experienced this?"* But this doesn't invite an answer, but rather speculation, suggestions, and ideas of how you might come upon an answer. This is a Q&A site where answers are expected to be *definitive*. Questions therefore must not require more information before they can be answered. You might find [ask] and the [tour] helpful.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator I see, thank you for the feed back.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from the comments. The best answer is to rule out devices owned by turning WiFi off on devices one by one while the ALF network signal is being received. That will eliminate the devices as the source of the signal or identify the device broadcasting the signal.

If the signal is not from a device owned, then reset the router and modem to factory settings. After factory reset set up the modem with the help of the ISP. Set up the router using WPA2 or better encryption (https://www.howtogeek.com/204697/wi-fi-security-should-you-use-wpa2-aes-wpa2-tkip-or-both/). Set a secure pass phrase using upper and lower case letters, numbers, and special characters. Connect the devices via WiFi using the WPA2 encryption and the new secure passphrase. This should ensure that an outside network isn't listening in on the network even if the ALF SSID is still present. Up dating the pass phrase regularly is a good practice.

Steps that may be taken to secure the network are hard wiring most of the devices, when possible, and using a VPN client on the WiFi network. The VPN client adds an extra layer of encryption. VPN's can cause the network to run slower. Also depending on where the VPN exits some sites my lose function. Testing the VPN before implementation may be a wise decision if performance is important.

Comment: Try using wiggle wifi or similar, drive around the new house on each street and alley way using it. You can walk if you want, it would be more accurate if you take sidewalks. Each pass increase the radius of the circle around your house. Go back home and download the .kml file to your computer and use it at http://www.gpsvisualizer.com using it this way is essentially triangulation of the SSID with gps. It should let you know where it's actually coming from. +1 for trying to answer your own question.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart That maybe a better solution than the one I came up with. Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking about a large WiFi network (WAN?). It would be a state initiative. I am over 150 miles away from the initial place I began seeing the network. I would think that with a signal as strong as it is it wouldn't go in and out like it does. It leads me to believe that it is one of my devices broadcasting the SSID. Why a device is broadcasting an SSID with an obscure reference to a cat eating alien on an 80's TV show, Assisted Living Facility, or Animal Liberation Front is probably the next question.